# Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month 01843

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using sql developer for the first time. I cant understand why this error is occuring.

```
 CREATE TABLE TOY_STORE 
   (    TOY_STORE_ID NUMBER(3,0), 
    TOY_STORE_NAME VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    CITY VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) DEFAULT 'DELHI', 
    PHONENUMBER" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    STORE_OPENING_TIME TIMESTAMP (6), 
    STORE_CLOSING_TIME TIMESTAMP (6), 
     CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST (TO_CHAR (STORE_OPENING_TIME, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP)) > 8 || NULL), 
     CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST (TO_CHAR (STORE_CLOSING_TIME, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP)) < 21 || NULL); 

INSERT INTO TOY_STORE 
VALUES(1, 'Kid''s Cave', 'Delhi', 9912312312, '2014-04-01 09:10:12', '2014-04-01 21:42:05');
```

Following was the error given:

Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month 01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month" *Cause:     *Action: Error starting at line : 1 in command - INSERT INTO TOY_STORE  VALUES(1, 'Kid''s Cave', 'Delhi', 9912312312, '04-2014-04 09:10:12', '04-2014-04 21:42:05') Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month 01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"

Comment: why does your sample code have `2014-04-01`, but your error message have `04-2014-01`? If that's what you're really feeding into the system, then there's your problem. you're telling oracle it's yyyy-mm-dd and feeding it mm-yyyy-dd

Comment: Why are you converting to a string and then casting back to a timestamp in your constraint? And why are you relying on implicit date/timestamp conversion, both in that constraint and in your insert? (You also have a stray double-quote and a missing closing parenthesis in your `create table`; it really helps if you show what you are actually running... and do you expect `||` to mean 'or'?)

Answer (score 0):

Your `create table` as shown in the question has a stray double-quote and is missing a closing parenthesis. Your check constraints are odd:

- you are converting a timestamp to a string using a specific format, and then casting back to a timestamp using the session `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`, which will fail for sessions which don't have the setting you expect;
- your are concatenating a null onto the hour value you're checking for, e.g. `21 || NULL`, which is converting it to a string. Pretty sure you want to allow that to be null so you're using `||` as `or`, which isn't correct; but you don't need to explicitly allow for that anyway.

```
CREATE TABLE TOY_STORE (
  TOY_STORE_ID NUMBER(3,0), 
  TOY_STORE_NAME VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  CITY VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) DEFAULT 'DELHI', 
  PHONENUMBER NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  STORE_OPENING_TIME TIMESTAMP (6), 
  STORE_CLOSING_TIME TIMESTAMP (6), 
  CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM STORE_OPENING_TIME) > 8), 
  CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM STORE_CLOSING_TIME) < 21)
);
```

You might want to consider naming your constraints; and you might want a lower bound on the closing time and an upper bound on the opening time, or at least make sure opening isn't after closing (unless you're allowing for night opening; in which case you probably wouldn't want those constraints at all).

Then you are inserting using a string literal, not a timestamp. You are again relying on implicit conversion using your client's `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` setting. The SQL Developer default for that is `DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF`, which means with `'2014-04-01 09:10:12`` it will try to map the parts of the string literal to the parts of the format mask and fail; that default model does give ORA-01843.

You should either convert your string with an explicit format mask, using `to_timestamp()`:

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE (TOY_STORE_ID, TOY_STORE_NAME, CITY, PHONENUMBER,
  STORE_OPENING_TIME, STORE_CLOSING_TIME)
VALUES(1, 'Kid''s Cave', 'Delhi', 9912312312,
  to_timestamp('2014-04-01 09:10:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
  to_timestamp('2014-04-01 21:42:05', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

or use ANSI timestamp literals:

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE (TOY_STORE_ID, TOY_STORE_NAME, CITY, PHONENUMBER,
  STORE_OPENING_TIME, STORE_CLOSING_TIME)
VALUES(1, 'Kid''s Cave', 'Delhi', 9912312312,
  timestamp '2014-04-01 09:10:12', timestamp '2014-04-01 21:42:05');
```

... which violates your constraint as expected:

```
SQL Error: ORA-02290: check constraint (SCHEMA.SYS_C00113492) violated
02290. 00000 -  "check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check           
*Action:   do not insert values that violate the constraint.
```

Notice the `SYS_C00113492` name; that's a system-generated name for your constraint. It will be easier to follow what is happening if you name your constraints.

You are still allowed to insert nulls:

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE (TOY_STORE_ID, TOY_STORE_NAME, CITY, PHONENUMBER,
  STORE_OPENING_TIME, STORE_CLOSING_TIME)
VALUES(1, 'Kid''s Cave', 'Delhi', 9912312312, null, null);

1 row inserted.
```

Comment: But I need to insert date and time together in store _closing_time and store_opening_time columns. It is still giving error as not a valid month

Comment: @Abhipriya - the first insert statement in my answer, using timestamp literals, is giving the date and time for those columns. Did you include the `timestamp` keyword? I've edited to show how to do it with `to_timestamp()` and an explicit format mask too.

Comment: When I used the create table and insert commands with to_timestamp , this time its showing the error as "Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12
01849. 00000 -  "hour must be between 1 and 12".

Comment: @Abhipriya - the format mask I showed had `HH24`; that error suggests you used `HH`. They are not the same thing. You must use an explicit format mask that actually matches the string value you are converting.

Comment: @ Alex - I have used exactly the same command you have mentioned. But it's not working. Can there be some other reasons for this???

Comment: @Abhipriya - you cannot get ORA-01849 with format mask `HH24`. I've just run the create and insert again, copied from my answer above. The insert got ORA-02290 because of the check constraint; with the closing time changed to `'2014-04-01 20:42:0'` the insert was successful. This is not rely on any NLS settings so you *must* be doing something different.

Comment: @ Alex -                                                                                            INSERT INTO TOY_STORE (TOY_STORE_ID, TOY_STORE_NAME, CITY, PHONENUMBER,
  STORE_OPENING_TIME, STORE_CLOSING_TIME)
VALUES(2, 'Kid''s Cav', 'Delhi', 9912812312,
  timestamp '2014-04-01 09:10:12', timestamp '2014-04-01 20:40:05'); Your this command is working.I made Mistake in the closing time. Thank you

Comment: @ Alex -How the following command violating the constraint                                'INSERT INTO TOY_STORE_NEW(TOY_STORE_ID,TOY_STORE_NAME,
PHONENUMBER,STORE_OPENING_TIME,STORE_CLOSING_TIME)
VALUES(5,'Uncle Sam Toys Den',
8112312310,
timestamp '2014-04-01 08:01:00',
timestamp '2014-04-01 20:00:00');' where store_opening time is >8, and showing error "SQL Error: ORA-02290: check constraint (HR.SYS_C0011181) violated
02290. 00000-"check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:The values being inserted do not satisfy named check
*Action:do not insert values that violate the constraint"

Comment: The **hour** is *not* greater than 8; it is exactly 8. Your constraint will not allow any time before 09:00:00.